# Multitouch code for mac

Tags: c

Hi I am unfamiliar with anything outside of Java and having some difficulties with the source code I've included. I think it is C++. I've since installed Xcode however it does not just plug and play. So is this actually C++? Is Xcode currently worth putting effort into? The end goal is to integrate into Touch Designer so is this even the right track?

"#include < math.h>"

"#include < unistd.h>"

"#include < CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>"

```
typedef struct { float x,y; } mtPoint;
typedef struct { mtPoint pos,vel; } mtReadout;

typedef struct {
  int frame;
  double timestamp;
  int identifier, state, foo3, foo4;
  mtReadout normalized;
  float size;
  int zero1;
  float angle, majorAxis, minorAxis; // ellipsoid
  mtReadout mm;
  int zero2[2];
  float unk2;
} Finger;

typedef void *MTDeviceRef;
typedef int (*MTContactCallbackFunction)(int,Finger*,int,double,int);

MTDeviceRef MTDeviceCreateDefault();
void MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(MTDeviceRef, MTContactCallbackFunction);
void MTDeviceStart(MTDeviceRef, int); // thanks comex


int callback(int device, Finger *data, int nFingers, double timestamp, int 
frame) {
  for (int i=0; i<nFingers; i++) {
    Finger *f = &data[i];
    printf("Frame %7d: Angle %6.2f, ellipse %6.3f x%6.3f; "
           "position (%6.3f,%6.3f) vel (%6.3f,%6.3f) "
           "ID %d, state %d [%d %d?] size %6.3f, %6.3f?\n",
       f->frame,
       f->angle * 90 / atan2(1,0),
       f->majorAxis,
       f->minorAxis,
       f->normalized.pos.x,
       f->normalized.pos.y,
       f->normalized.vel.x,
       f->normalized.vel.y,
       f->identifier, f->state, f->foo3, f->foo4,
       f->size, f->unk2);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  MTDeviceRef dev = MTDeviceCreateDefault();
  MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(dev, callback);
  MTDeviceStart(dev, 0);
  printf("Ctrl-C to abort\n");
  sleep(-1);
  return 0;
}
run: test
    ./test
test: test.m
    gcc -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -framework MultitouchSupport $^ -o $@ -std=c99
```

Comment: The hint about the language comes from the name of the source file: `test.m`. It's neither C nor C++.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). Objective-C is a C-like language that was mainly used by Apple but has been recently replaced by Swift.